# Laravel 5.2 Get all users with Role (Entrust)

Tags: php, laravel

Basically I just want to dump all the users with a certain role. When I do:

```
$users = User::with('roles')->get();
```

I get all the users and roles added on the users like so:

```
{
 id: 1,
 first_name: "P",
 last_name: "Tag",
 email: "packy@test.com",
 phone: "5555555555",
 avatar: "",
 last_login: "2016-07-13 23:49:23",
 created_at: "2016-07-13 23:25:05",
 updated_at: "2016-07-13 23:49:23",
 roles: [
  {
   id: 1,
   name: "owner",
   display_name: "Admin",
   description: "Admin user that has full access",
   created_at: "2016-06-07 00:00:00",
   updated_at: "2016-06-07 00:00:00",
     pivot: {
      user_id: 1,
      role_id: 1
     }
  }
 ]
},
```

Great now I just want to get the users with a roles name of a certain value. I imagine my query would look like this but not sure how to write it:

```
$users = User::with('roles')->where('roles->name', '=', 'owner')->get();
```

but that of course doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So this is what I did to get it to work. For anyone else with issues look at the Laravel Eloquent Relationship docs, that is where I solved my problem.

```
 $users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
            $query->where('name', '=', 'owner');
 })->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like this, if you are using eloquent relationship. And this is inverse relationship.

```
$users = Role::where('name', 'owner')->first()->users;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify additional query constraints for the eager loading query like this:

```
$users = User::with(['roles' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', '=', 'owner');
}])->get();
```

**Update:** if you want to specify additional query constraints to users table you can chain them like this:

```
$users = User::with(['roles' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', '=', 'owner');
}])->where('role_id', '<>', null)->->get();
```

Note: not sure if role_id or what in your database so this for illustrate.

Comment: Hmmm I get what this is supposed to do but now it returns all the users, just those whose role is Owner has that appended to the JSON, those who do not are still lists but with no role.

Comment: so you want to query the user table not the eager loaded query! ok see the updated answer

Comment: Hey, havent tried your answer but I figured it out. You can check out my answer if you want. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use your query like this:-

```
$users = App\User::with(['roles' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'owner');
}])->get();
```